# Running Python script with import causing issues

Tags: python, raspberry-pi4

I have a custom python script which sends emails, when I created it in Thonny and ran it all works fine.
However when I try to run it at start up or in the terminal I get the following error:

*sudo python sendcpuwarning.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sendcpuwarning.py", line 2, in 
import sendmail

File "/home/pi/Scripts/sendmail.py", line 4, in 
from email.message import EmailMessage
ImportError: cannot import name EmailMessage*

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Maybe you haven't activated virtualenv? Is your IDE creating venv automatically for each new project? Then you have to `source venv/bin/activate`

Comment: ...or just different versions of Python maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Worked it out, the issue was I was calling python /script/location instead of python3 /script/location.